# Looking for best practices for using a Linux box as a file server in MS workgroup

Tags: linux, windows, networking, file-sharing

I've got a number of Windows (7/Vista/XP) based machines on a network that have no unifying structure (i.e. no ADC, PDC or for that matter a workgroup).

I recently added a Linux box with a fairly sizable raid setup that I'd like to use as a file server.

***What would be considered a best practice for making the storage on the Linux box available to the windows clients on the network?***

It seems my options are:

- creating SMB shares - on Vista at least this restricts a user to logging into only one SAMBA acount at a time.
- Installing a PDC on the Linux box, and making a network

Suggestions?

Comment: If you have more than a couple of machines you should really try and create a decent structured network. The small effort involved will be repaid many times over. It sounds like this would be a good time to do it.

Comment: Sure thing.  But I've not the space or resources to drop in hardware.  What would you be suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Im using my CentOS with TGTD (IMHO iSCSI is bit faster than SMB ;) ) in my local network where most of machines are running on MS systems.
So in my case iSCSI with chap authentication working perfectly :).
So if U decide to use iSCSI You may try to run IETD or SCST for example :).

Comment: Wow.  I don't understand much of what you wrote at all.  TGTD? iSCSI? IETD? SCST?

Comment: @Jamie iSCSI is a block-level sharing protocol used for storage, not that useful if you need multiple servers talking to the same blocks. The other four letter acronyms are separate iSCSI stacks for Linux. For completeness, there is also target_core.